# Number of intersection regions made by multiple circles

Tags: algorithm, intersection

We are given four parameters to draw some circles:

1. center of the circles(x_1 and x_2),both are located on the x axis
2. the maximum radius(k_1 and k_2)
   this is how we use this info:the first set of circles center is located at `x_1`,we draw  k_1 circles from here with different radii starting from 1 to k_1:`(1<= r_1 <= k_1)`  so the first circle has the radius of 1 and centered at x_1 ,the second one has the radius of 2 ... the same conditions apply on the second set of circles.In the end there are some circles that may or may not intersect with each other.What I want is the total number of regions that are made in the end.I think if I understand what separates two regions the the problem is mainly solved.To clear things here are some examples(note that all parameter are in the: [1,10^5] range):

   `for:x_1 = 1,k_1 = 1,x_2 = 0,k_2 = 1   => n = 3`
   `for: x_1 = 0,k_1 = 1,x_2 = 2,k_2 = 1   => n = 2`
   `for:x_1 = 3,k_1 = 3,x_2 = 7,k_2 = 4   => n =16`

Comment: So `x_1` and `x_2` are what we typically call `(x,y)` coordinates?

Comment: @JimMischel I think from the example that the `(x,y)` coordinates of the center are `(x1, 0)` and `(x2, 0)`.

Comment: @btilly Upon re-reading the question, I think you're right.

Comment: Why don't you try drawing yourself a few pictures, using those examples? That will let you see the intersection areas.

Comment: @JimMischel Of course I tried that(that is how I found the number of regions in my examples) but I need a algorithm that can give the final result just using the variables I introduced in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have come up with following solution.

As you wrote, we have two sets of circles. Center of one set is `x_1` and center of other set is `x_2` Let's denote the sets as `L` and `R`, where

`L` = the set of circles whose center is `x_1` and 
`R` = the set of circles whose center is `x_2` and `x_1 <= x_2`.

Now algorithm steps:

1. First check whether the centers for `L` and `R` (`x_1` and `x_2`) are equal or not. If equal, then the two sets are homo-centered. So the answer is the maximum of `k_1` and `k_2`.
2. We have to make sure `x_1 <= x_2`. If `x_1 > x_2`, then swap (`x_1`, `x_2`).
3. In this algorithm first we'll calculate the count of regions in each circle of set `L`. Then we'll calculate the the count of region in set `R` those are outside of `x_1 + k_1`. So to keep things well we need to 
   swap `k_1` and `k_2`, if and only if `k_1 < k_2` meets.
4. Now `x_1 <= x_2` is true and we'll count the all regions inside of each circle in set `L`. Then iterate over all positions from `x_1 + 1` to `x_1 + k_1` and do as follows and try to catch the calculation of region count for different cases from the figure:

[image]
[image]

**Special case:**
[image]

5. Still we have to check another thing. Add the count of region in set `R` those are outside of `x_1 + k_1`.

   - if x_1 + k_1 <= x_2 + k_2 then `dif = (x_2 + k_2) - (x_1 + k_1)` and `result = result + min(k_2, dif)`

[image]

Here is my `c++` implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int intersection_count(int x_1, int k_1, int x_2, int k_2) {
    if (x_1 == x_2)
        return max(k_1, k_2);

    if (x_1 > x_2) {
        swap(x_1, x_2);
    }
    if (k_1 < k_2) {
        swap(k_1, k_2);
    }

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k_1; i++) {
        int pos = x_1 + i;
        int rev_pos = x_1 - i;
        if (pos <= x_2 - k_2) {
            result++;
        }
        else if (pos <= x_2) {
            int dif = pos - (x_2 - k_2);

            // check if the ith circle is cmpletely inside range [x_2 - k_2, x_2 + k_2]
            dif -= (rev_pos < x_2 - k_2) ? 0 : (rev_pos - (x_2 - k_2) + 1);

            result += 2*dif;
        }
        else if (pos <= x_2 + k_2) {
            int dif = (x_2 + k_2) - pos + 1;

            // check if the ith circle is cmpletely inside range [x_2 - k_2, x_2 + k_2]
            dif -= (rev_pos < x_2 - k_2) ? 0 : (rev_pos - (x_2 - k_2) + 1);

            result += 2*dif;
        }
        else {
            result++;
        }
    }
    if (x_1 + k_1 <= x_2 + k_2) {
        int dif = (x_2 + k_2) - (x_1 + k_1);
        result += min(k_2, dif);
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << intersection_count(1, 1, 0, 1) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(0, 1, 2, 1) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(3, 3, 7, 4) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(0, 1, 0, 2) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(2, 1, 3, 2) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(2, 1, 3, 3) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(3, 4, 5, 3) << endl;
    cout << intersection_count(0, 7, 2, 7) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tnx for the answer but there is a bug,conside for instance:`0 1 0 2` basically it is a circle inside another one and the result should be `2` but this algorithm returns `5`.

Comment: @FarzinNasiri Thanks for pointing out that case. I just forgot to handle this case while writing solution. It was on my mind. But somehow I forgot that.

Comment: Tnx for fixing the last bug,but I think I found another one!!!consider 2 1 3 2 it should return 4 but this algorithm returns 6! I think it is because now one of the inner circles is tangent to the outer circle.The big problem with this question is that there are so many special cases to be checked.

Comment: @FarzinNasiri Yes. You are absolutely right. It's my bad. I've just checked the general case. I should handle it with more care. I think I have a solution. Let me try this.

Comment: @FarzinNasiri I've edited the solution. I think its ok now. Thanks for correcting me again.

Comment: I am very sorry I put you into so many problems !but I think I found another bug`3 4 5 3`.If you count them the result would be 19 but the algorithm gives back 21.The problem is with the first time the for loops executes. It counts 2 extra regions.

Comment: if we concider `3 4 5 3 ` .Then x2-k2 is less than x1+1 and x2,this scenario has never occurred in  previous examples. I think that is the problem

Comment: Can you please add the logic of your code to your solution?

Comment: Sure. Sorry for being late.